# Popover card effect in Flutter/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have often seen the screen effect as in this video: https://youtube.com/shorts/TkwHLuiconE

That is, a new sandboxed screen, opens, pretty much completely overlays the old screen, the old screen shrinks a bit, the screen is dismissible by dragging down.

What is this effect called? Can it be done in Flutter?

Comment: CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition or CupertinoPopupSurface

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in flutter and it can be achieved using CupertinoPopupSurface or CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition widgets.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34747328)